# Find the mean function of a moving average. Question 1.6 in Shumway Stoffer Time Series Analysis book

Tags: time-series

> Consider the time series
>
> $$x_t = \beta_1 + \beta_2 t + w_t$$
>
> where $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are known constants and $w_t$ is a white
> noise process with variance $\sigma^2_w$.
>
> Show that the mean of the moving average
>
> $$v_t=\frac{1}{(2q+1)} \sum_{j=-q}^{q} x_{t-j}$$
>
> is $\beta_1+\beta_2t$, and give a simplified expression for the
> autocovariance function.

What I have is

$$\mu_{t-j} = E(x_{t-j}) = \beta_1 + \beta_2 t - \beta_2 j$$

$$E[v_t] =\frac{1}{(2q+1)} \sum_{j=-q}^{q} E(x_{t-j})=\frac{1}{(2q+1)} \left[2q (\beta_1 + \beta_2 t) + \sum_{j=-q}^{q} \beta_2 j \right]$$

seems like it should be easy from here, but I just can't see it.

Comment: Use $\sum_{j=-q}^q j = 0$ and note that the sum has $2q+1$ terms, not $2q$ of them.

Comment: got it.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mu_{t-j} = E(x_{t-j}) = \beta_1 + \beta_2 t - \beta_2 j$$

$$\sum_{j=-q}^{q} \beta_2 j = 0\quad \text{ because of symmetry.}$$

And note there are $2q + 1$ terms in series $j = -q,...,q$

So we have

$$E[v_t] =\frac{1}{(2q+1)} \sum_{j=-q}^{q} E(x_{t-j})$$

$$=\frac{1}{(2q+1)} [(2q +1) (\beta_1 + \beta_2 t) + \sum_{j=-q}^{q} \beta_2 j]$$

$$= \frac{2q + 1}{2q+1} \beta_1+\beta_2 t$$

$$=  \beta_1+\beta_2 t$$